# Orgmode title levels height

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm trying to set the font sizes of org-mode titles.
They are, by default, too big (yeah, size does matter).

I've been trying to find a reference, but very annoyingly, I couldn't.
How do I customize the scale value of all headlines through my config file?
Via group settings inside emacs --> org-faces I've found that it's set to height and scale.
I want to set all scales to 1.

Answer (score 12):

Found the answer. Too obvious, but still annoying.

```
(custom-set-faces
  '(org-level-1 ((t (:inherit outline-1 :height 1.0))))
  '(org-level-2 ((t (:inherit outline-2 :height 1.0))))
  '(org-level-3 ((t (:inherit outline-3 :height 1.0))))
  '(org-level-4 ((t (:inherit outline-4 :height 1.0))))
  '(org-level-5 ((t (:inherit outline-5 :height 1.0))))
)
```

Comment: My headers' font size were the same as the text, except when i used this particular theme.  Just curious now, could this the same issue as you are having?  I.e., the theme is messing up your headers font size.

Comment: Might be, though I'm using the same theme as before - monokai.

Comment: Thanks, @nymo, that was my issue. I didn't notice as I've never used org without solarized. The fix: `(setq solarized-scale-org-headlines nil)`

Comment: Aren't these for the headings not for the title?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using doom emacs you may try this (replace doom-city-lights with your theme):

```
(custom-theme-set-faces!
'doom-city-lights      
'(org-level-4 :inherit outline-4 :height 1.1)      
'(org-level-3 :inherit outline-3 :height 1.25)      
'(org-level-2 :inherit outline-2 :height 1.5)      
'(org-level-1 :inherit outline-1 :height 1.75)      
'(org-document-title :height 2.0 :underline nil))
```

Or you could just hook doom-docs-mode after org-mode (which turns on all "prettifications"):

```
(add-hook! 'org-mode-hook 'doom-docs-mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution by Daniel Didn't worked for changing #+Title Font size / height.
What I got working on a custom theme on spacemacs.
by editing dotfilespacemacs that is .spacemacs > (defun dotspacemacs/emacs-custom-settings () section or your regular init.el in case of stock Emacs.

```
(custom-set-faces
  '(org-level-1 ((t (:inherit outline-1 :height 2.0))))
  '(org-level-2 ((t (:inherit outline-2 :height 1.8))))
  '(org-level-3 ((t (:inherit outline-3 :height 1.6))))
  '(org-level-4 ((t (:inherit outline-4 :height 1.4))))
  '(org-level-5 ((t (:inherit outline-5 :height 1.0))))
  (set-face-attribute 'org-document-title nil :height 2.0)
```

Thanks for solutions Provided by Mr/Miss Viking667 and habamax on IRC All credits to them for their help.